# Clipboard data adds random returns to text

Tags: javascript, html, events

When I try to get the data from the clipboard with `event.clipboardData.getData('text/html')` the resulting html contains return keys that shouldn't be present.

The result is:

```html
 <p class=Tabeltekst style='mso-yfti-cnfc:1'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:
  normal'><span style='mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt;color:black;mso-color-alt:windowtext'>Inhoudelijke
  punten student</span></b><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span
          style='mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
```

While the expected outcome is:

```html
<p class='Tabeltekst' style='mso-yfti-cnfc:1'><b style='mso-bidi-font-weight:  normal'><span
          style='mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt;color:black;mso-color-alt:windowtext'>Inhoudelijke  punten student</span></b><b
          style='mso-bidi-font-weight:normal'><span style='mso-bidi-font-size:8.0pt'><o:p></o:p></span></b></p>
```

without any enters between "inhoudelijke" and "punten".
Also when looking at the data from the clipboard in a console.log it seems as if the clipboard data has a max width before just forcing everything to a new line. Is this correct and if so, can I change this to prevent linebreaks?

Comment: Have you / how have you checked that those newlines aren't in the original text? Since runs of whitespace (including newlines) in HTML are treated as a single space...

Comment: I've checked the original xml of the word document and it doesn't show any new lines, empty paragraphs etc. that would cause a line break.

Comment: *"the original xml of the word document"* What does this mean? Can you explain precisely where the data got copied to the clipboard? The `text/html` clipboard data is generally set when you copy elements from a web-page, in a browser. I really don't know well MS-Word, but last time I used it (years ago), as far as I remember it wasn't displaying HTML documents, and thus, it wouldn't have set `text/html` clipboardData, but just `text/plain` one. When copied from a webpage, I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/4ufh1v30/ (Chrome adds a lot of noise, but no new lines)

Comment: A docx file is made up of several xml files. One of which is the xml file where the structure is saved of the document (tables, paragraphs etc.) when copying and pasting this in chrome it can be processed in getData as either ``text/html`` or ``Text``. The data I'm trying to paste is copied from a docx file that contains a table (nothing special, just a table).

Comment: What is it about the linebreaks that bothers you? Again, it's perfectly valid HTML, and runs of whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) are a single space in HTML. So...?

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a bug in handsontable (the package we use to display tables).